# gcc returns undefined reference when breaking up a C program into multiple files

Tags: c, gcc, ld

I've been provided a sample C file and I'd like to break it up into a pair of .c files and a .h file.  I'm having trouble getting the program to compile after splitting everything, but I think it's a simple solution.  My C is just rusty.

**capture.h**

```
#ifndef __CAPTURE_H
#define __CAPTURE_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include "master.h"
#include "pvcam.h"

static void AcquireStandard( int16 hCam, int16 num_frames, uns32 exp_time );
void setROI( rgn_type* roi, uns16 s1, uns16 s2, uns16 sbin, uns16 p1, uns16 p2, uns16 pbin );
void printROI( int16 roi_count, rgn_type* roi );
void print_pv_error( );
void setFullFrame( int16 hcam, rgn_type* roi );
#endif
```

**capture.c**

```
#include "capture.h"

void AcquireStandard( int16 hCam, int16 num_frames, uns32 exp_time ) {
... Does lots of stuff ...
}
... Many other functions, etc...
```

**pixis.c**

```
    #include "capture.h"

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        char cam_name[CAM_NAME_LEN];    /* camera name                    */
        int16 hCam;                     /* camera handle                  */
        int16 cam_selection;
        int16 num_frames, circ_buff_size, buffer_type;
        uns32 port, shtr_open_mode;
        uns32 enum_param, exp_time;
        int16 adc_index;
        int16 gain;
        uns16 exp_res_index;
        char *s;
        ..... snip .....
        AcquireStandard( hCam, num_frames, exp_time );
        pl_cam_close( hCam );
    pl_pvcam_uninit();
    return 0;
}
```

I snipped out a lot of irrelevant stuff.  When I compile, I get the following error:

```
gcc -o pixis pixis.o capture.o -I/usr/local/pvcam/examples -lpvcam -ldl -lpthread -lraw1394
pixis.o: In function `main':
pixis.c:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `AcquireStandard'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [pixis] Error 1
```

AcquireStandard is in the .o file, I checked it with nm:

```
    nm capture.o 
00000000 t AcquireStandard
00000000 d _master_h_
00000004 d _pvcam_h_
         U fclose
         U fopen
         U free
         U fwrite
         U malloc
         U pl_error_code
         U pl_error_message
         U pl_exp_check_status
         U pl_exp_finish_seq
         U pl_exp_init_seq
         U pl_exp_setup_seq
         U pl_exp_start_seq
         U pl_exp_uninit_seq
         U pl_get_param
00000350 T printROI
00000440 T print_pv_error
         U printf
         U puts
00000489 T setFullFrame
000002d4 T setROI
```

Now I'm stumped.  Did something change in gcc in the last few years or did I just forget some simple detail?

Comment: Remove the `static` keyword from your prototype on `AcquireStandard()` in the header... it's no longer a static function.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I appreciate the thought on that -- but I think the question should actually be closed/deleted as being just a typo and unlikely to help others in the future. (Others could certainly end up having a similar problem, but there's practically no chance of them stumbling across this question when trying to solve it.) I'm glad you've got past the issue though!

Comment: @mah: I don't agree on that. Just because this is a rather rare problem, it's not said it might not help others. Actually, refactoring (which this is all about) is a pretty common (and desireable) task that others may thankful about any pointers if gone wrong.

Comment: Well, I'll provide it as an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `AcquireStandard()` function was originally prototyped to be `static`, meaning its visibility was constrained to the file it was implemented in. In this refactoring, the function's visibility is required to reach out to other sources -- but the header still has the `static` keyword on the function.

Notice also the output of the `nm` command, specifically the differences between these two lines representing functions in the source:

```
00000000 t AcquireStandard
00000489 T setFullFrame
```

The `T` indicates a function in the object's text that has global visibility, while the `t` tells you the visibility is local.

Remove `static` on the prototype in `capture.h` and the problem will be solved.